# Using Session data in SQL SELECT parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Okay, so I've got the follwing mark up:

Here I have a listbox that is to be populated by some SQL query.

```
            <asp:ListBox ID="MyListBox" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="MyDataSource" DataTextField="Field1" DataValueField="ID" ></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Field1] FROM [Table1] WHERE ([ID2] = @ID2)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID2" 
                        SessionField="ID2" DbType="Guid"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

A few problems that I have:

The list box always is empty and when I try and test the query, it always presents a dialogue box asking for me to input "Type" "DbType" and "Value". I'm not too sure what to pick here.

I've tried running the application, ensuring that there is the needed session data in the correct key. (`Session["ID2"]` has been given a `Guid`). However, when I get to the listbox, it's empty even though I can look at the table data and know what should be there.

Comment: If you set `Session["ID2"] = Guid.NewGuid()`, can you then do the reverse i.e. `Guid value = (Guid)Session["ID2"]`? Just so we're sure that there is a value there?

Comment: Yes I've checked that out. Although I'm using `Guid.Parse()`.
It does store and load the `Guid` fine.

Comment: When is the session variable getting set? Wondering if it is to do with the page rendering order, for instance is the list box getting rendered before setting the session variable?

Comment: I have a WizardControl which asks the user to input stuff. A button gets pressed and then the session var is set. Then the user navigates forwards in the WizardControl and eventually reaches the ListBox. The content of the ListBox is made by the user in the previous step or is already there in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Basically, I assumed that the query should return results when it rightly shouldn't have done. Additionally, the data in `Field1` was an empty string. So when it did return results, I wouldn't see anything in the ListBox.